# $.each display data then pause for 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, timeout

I'm iterating a JSON file using .each(). I want my page to show data for say 3 seconds, pause for 3 seconds then move on to the next one and repeat. I have this code:

```
    $.getJSON(url,function(json1){
                    $.each(json1.data,function(numb){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            alert(json1.data[numb]["title"]);   
                        },3000);

                    });     

            });
```

I thought this would do it but this only waits for 3 seconds and then displays each bit of data in succession, and I need them to be 3 seconds apart.

How do I get that? Thanks!

EDIT: ok, so with this code:
var num=0;

```
                $.getJSON(url,function(json1){

                    $.each(json1.data,function(broj){

                        setTimeout(function() {

                            $(".bubble").text(json1.data[broj]["text"]);    

                        },6000*num);
                        num++;
                    });



            });
```

But this is about half a second late to other elements that use setInterval(func,3000) to display data. Why and can it be fixed? I'm really interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Times by the index:-

```js
$.getJSON(url, function(json1) {
  $.each(json1.data, function(numb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert(json1.data[numb]["title"]);
    }, 3000 * num);
  });
});
```

This will make the 1st 0 seconds, 2nd 3 seconds, 3rd 6 seconds, etc.

or it you want the 1st to wait also, use:

```
3000 * (num+1)
```

Comment: Why does this kind of go off late? it doesn't really start right away, it's about a second late. it's a problem because I have other things that go off with setInterval(f,3000) and they don't sync.

Answer (score 1):

This is because setTimeout isn't blocking, so the each loop flies through declaring all the timeouts and then 3 seconds later they all fire.  You could probably instead chain the setTimeouts together almost calling them recursively. Inside each setTimeout you would call the next setTimeout passing it the next data element instead of the each loop (May still need some type of counter to increment so you have an index to the item. Increment it and do the bounds checking in setTimeout.).  That way the next setTimeout isn't declared until the previous completes.

I actually just did something recently setting an alert bar to change every 5 seconds showing text from an array like:

```
var speed = 5000;    /*this is the time in milliseconds adjust to suit*/

    function showAlert(x) {
        if (!x || x > (sysAlert.length - 1) || x < 0) x = 0;
        document.getElementById("alertBar").innerHTML = sysAlert[x];
        return setTimeout(showAlert, speed, ++x);
    }
    showAlert(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 0;

$.each(mydata, function(data){
count++;
setTimeout(function() {
                        console.log(data);   
                    },3000 * count);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the index `numb` is numeric:

```
$.getJSON(url,function(json1){

    var numb = 0; // starting point of array

    var iterate = function(){
        if(json1.data[numb]){ // only setTimeout if this index exists
            alert(json1.data[numb++]["title"]);
            setTimeout(iterate, 3000);
        }
    }

    // show the first result immediately
    iterate();

    // OR

    // show the first result 3000 milliseconds after the data is loaded
    // setTimeout(iterate, 3000);
});
```